# Mongoose Models: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-models

I try to import a model from the file where I create it (the same file where I connect the database) and when I try to work with it, it is "undefined".

```js
const { model } = require("../database");

model.findOne(. . .).then(. . .
```

This is the file I connect/create with

```js
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
    dbName: "x"
}).then(async () => {

    const db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', err => console.error);

    const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        . . .
    });

    const model = mongoose.model('userprofiles', schema );

    module.exports = {
        mongoose,
        db,
        model
    };
});
```

I went through many posts on GitHub Issues and here on StackOverflow and none have given me a concise, working answer

I tried with "autoCreate" that I saw in an Issue on Github, but it didn't work, the same thing happened

```js
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
    dbName: "x",
    autoCreate: true
}).then(async () => {

    . . .
    
    const model = mongoose.model('userprofiles', schema );
    await model.init();

    module.exports = {
        mongoose,
        db,
        model
    };
});
```

I should clarify that if I work directly on the model file it works perfectly well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate your exports from creating a database connection. Modules are loaded synchronously, so if you declare `module.exports` inside an (asynchronous) callback, it won't be declared at the time the file is `require()`'d.

It's perfectly okay with Mongoose to create models without a connection being present.

Something like this:

```
mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
    dbName: "x"
}).then(() => {
    const db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on('error', err => console.error);
});

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    . . .
});

const model = mongoose.model('userprofiles', schema );

module.exports = { mongoose, model };
```

If you need access to the connection from other parts of your app, you can use `mongoose.connection`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use callbacks

```
const { model } = require("../database");

model.findOne({_id : 12489e}, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

> **Note:** The `_id` depends on whatever you are querying for.
> Could be `name` or whatever.
>
> Also make sure that you're running the `mongod` command in your terminal.

Comment: I keep getting the same error, `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')`

Comment: Then there's probably an error with your database. Try checking viewing the data using the `mongo` command or [Download Studio3t](https://studio3t.com/download/) for a better view.